# Is there a deep reason why springs combine like capacitors?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, energy-conservation, capacitance, spring

I was solving a practice Physics GRE and there was a question about springs connected in series and parallel. I was too lazy to derive the way the spring constants add in each case. But I knew how capacitances and resistances add when they are connected in series/parallel. So I reasoned that spring constants should behave as capcitances because both springs and capacitors store energy.

This line reasoning did give me the correct answer for how spring constants add, but I was just curious if this analogy makes sense, and if it does, how far one can take it. That is, knowing just that two things store energy, what all can you say will be similar for the two things.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Electrical analogies of mechanical elements such as springs, masses, and dash pots provide the answer.  The "deep" connection is simply that the differential equations have the same form.

In electric circuit theory, the *across* variable is voltage while the *through* variable is current.

The analogous quantities in mechanics are force and velocity.  Note that in both cases, the product of the across and through variables has the unit of power.

(An aside, sometimes it is convenient to use force and velocity as the across and through variables respectively while other times, it is more convenient to switch those roles.)

Now, assuming velocity is the through variable, velocity and electric current are analogous.  Thus, displacement and electric charge are analogous.

For a spring, we have $f = kd \rightarrow d = \frac{1}{k}f$ while for a capacitor we have $Q = CV$.

For a mass, we have $f = ma = m\dot v $ while for an inductor we have $V = L \dot I$

Finally, for a dashpot, we have $f = Bv$ while for a resistor we have $V = RI$.

So, we have

$\frac{1}{k} \rightarrow C$

$m \rightarrow L$

$B \rightarrow R$

For a nice summary with examples, see [this](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Analogs/ElectricalMechanicalAnalogs.html).

UPDATE:  In another answer, RubenV questions the answer given above.  His reasoning requires an update.

> Alfred Centauri's answer is not correct. The analogy he mentions is
>   true, but it is irrelevant as it does not tell you anything about
>   components in series or in parallel.

In fact, it *is* relevant and it *does* tell you everything about components in series or in parallel.  Let's review:

When two circuit elements are in **parallel**, the **voltage** across each is identical.

When two circuit elements are in **series**, the **current** through each is identical.

This is fundamental and *must be kept in mind when moving to the mechanical analogy*.

In the mechanical analogy where a spring is the mechanical analog of a capacitor:

**force** is the analog of **voltage**

**velocity** is the analog of **current**.

Keeping this in mind, consider two springs connected in *mechanical* parallel and note that the *velocity* (rate of change of displacement) for each spring is identical.

But recall, in this analogy, velocity is the analog of current.  Thus, the equivalent electrical analogy is two capacitors *in series* (identical *current*).

In series, capacitance combines as so:

$\dfrac{1}{C_{eq}} = \dfrac{1}{C_1} + \dfrac{1}{C_2}$

With the spring analogy, $C \rightarrow \frac{1}{k}$ , this becomes:

$k_{eq} = k_1 + k_2$

The key point to take away from this is that **mechanical parallel is, in this analogy, circuit series** since, in mechanical parallel, the *velocity* (current) is the same, not the force (voltage).

For example, consider dash pots (resistors).  Two dash pots in "parallel" combine like two resistors in series, i.e., the resistance to motion of two dash pots in "parallel" is *greater* then each individually.

Now, if the roles of the analogous variables are swapped, if force is like current and velocity is like voltage, then mechanical parallel is like circuit parallel.  However, in this analogy, *mass* is like capacitance.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot draw this conclusion from a naive "they both store energy" argument (though you can use it as a mnemonic if you find it helps you).

Capacitances are usually measured in farads which corresponds to coulombs squared per joule while spring constants are usually measured in newtons per metre equivalent to joules per metre squared.

If you did your calculations with joules in a consistent position in the unit, for example using using reciprocal capacitance (elastance?), I think you would find the parallel and series composition calculations were reversed (and reciprocal capacitance would behave more like resistance and inductance).

Answer (score 3):

Stiffnesses add when the springs are connected "in parallel" (side by side):
$F = F_1 + F_2$;
$x_1 = x_2 = x$;
$k_x = k_1 x + k_2 x$;
$k_x = k_1 + k_2$.

Compliances add when the springs are connected "in series" (end to end):
$F_1 = F_2 = F$;
$x = x_1 + x_2$;
$s_ F = s_1 F + s_2 F$;
$s_ = s_1 + s_2$.

This is what I mean by "the math changes"-- the physics is obviously the same, but the form of the equations is different. I am calling into question your ability to jump from "they store energy" to "they add in parallel (and add as inverses in series)" by pointing out that with the use of compliances rather than stiffnesses, the opposite equations (representing of course the same physics) are obtained.

As for inductors-- why are capacitors a better analogy than inductors?Hm. How does your reasoning stand up to the following objections?

We are used to working with the stiffness or rate of springs k, defined by $F = k x$. But it is no less reasonable to work with the compliance $s = 1 / k$, defined by $x = s F$. This does not change the fundamental fact that springs store energy, nor that they can be viewed as the electrical analogues of capacitors. But the math changes!

Alternatively, consider inductors, which also store energy, and are typically characterized by the inductance L defined by $V=L. di/dt$. Do inductances add like capacitances or like resistances?